# javascript schedular plugins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

In our organization resource allocation to projects is done as follows, it is done by a Microsoft excel sheet.

Projects are in the horizontal side, people are in the vertical side, each cell contains the percentage the resources are allocated to the project.

[image]

I was given the task of putting this to a web application. For this purpose I have Googled and found there are many options to go to with in particular I went through.

1. [kendoui scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index)
2. [DayPilot for JavaScript](http://javascript.daypilot.org/scheduler/)
3. [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/demo/options.html)

Neither of them have the capability of **being modified** to the task I am required to do.

Are there any good libraries out there I can use and modify according to my needs?
I'm interested doing this using PHP, MYSQL and JavaScript(jQuery)

Comment: **jquery full calendar** would be helpful http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Ext Scheduler http://www.bryntum.com/products/scheduler/examples/. You can find many different uses for that and it's a well known javascript framework (the Ext).

You can find a working PHP + Ext Scheduler example here: http://www.bryntum.com/products/scheduler/download/?e=